# How to make imacros WAIT if a specific text string exists on a website?

Tags: imacros

Question in the title

Is there a non JavaScript method

Can I use eval command

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can build on this to wait if a certain String exists:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=HTM
SET timeout_time EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.includes('text to find')? 5 : 0")
WAIT SECONDS={{timeout_time}}
```

I just used a [TAG](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG) that grabs everything, feel free to change that to look for your String in a more narrow context. The extracted text is then searched for your `text to find`, if it exists it will wait 5 seconds, otherwise 0.